# How to show username between html with PHP

Tags: php, html

My issue is: I have a login system and I wanna show the current username in the page.

calendar.php:

// SOME CODE

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Welcome <? echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li> <!-- class="active" -->
        <li><a href="#">Store location <span class="label label-danger">65</span></a></li>
      </ul>
```

// SOME CODE

This shows the "Welcome" but don't show username...
How can I do this? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: where are you setting `$_SESSION['username']` ?

Comment: in another page... index.php

Comment: Have you started the session in *this* page?

Comment: I just tried it, but it throws the message: "Headers already been sent...."

Comment: @daniel_serretti please mark and up-vote the answer for others help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a rather old system, you need

```
<li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a></li>
```

If it still doesn't show, ensure that the page is being parsed for PHP. Then, make sure that $_SESSION['username'] has a value.

Comment: how can I have sure that my page is being parsed for PHP? my file name is calendar.php

Comment: ```<? != "old system"```

Comment: @daniel_serretti by saving the page as `.php` file, it will be automatically processed as a PHP file by the server, before the output of the file (ie the data) is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `$_SESSION['username']` is already set, i.e:

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "someusername";
```

---

**calendar.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li> <!-- class="active" -->
    <li><a href="#">Store location <span class="label label-danger">65</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

---

**Note:**

Ensure `session_start();` is the first statement on the script, i.e.:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Otherwise you may get the error:

> "Headers already sent..."

---

Learn how to use php sessions across multiple files [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to write php in your code:--

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li> <!-- class="active" -->
        <li><a href="#">Store location <span class="label label-danger">65</span></a></li>
      </ul>
```

Note:-

1.This code file name will be .php not .html and if your Session have username index and have some value then only it will show.

2.As you asked for the error you need to put this code on very upside of your php page

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'any user name';
```

After that my above code and then everything works fine.

3.If you want this session value to any other page on that page write first  `session_start();` on top and then you will get the value.

Comment: I already said that if you have Session varaibale with name  usensame and have some value then only you will got value here. Since your session have no variable with name username so this error occur.

Comment: $_SESSION was not found... how can I get this $_SESSION from my other page that has my attributes (index.php) ???

Comment: Sure, my $_SESSION variable has all I need when I was in index.php, but when I redirect to calendar.php it seems $_SESSION lose it's attributes.. How can I recover these attributes from another page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77351/discussion-between-daniel-serretti-and-anant-kumar-singh).